# Links are disabled throughout Office 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010, security-warning

I am having a problem where I cannot click on links in any Office 2010 program.  Whenever I click a link I get the following error message:

> This operation has been canceled due to restrictions in effect on this computer.  Please contact your system administrator.

It does not matter if I created the link, it does not matter if the link is to another file on my computer.  I am running everything in a standard, non-admin account.

**What I've tried so far**

- Run Office in a full admin account
- Set IE8 as default browser and reset all web settings
- Play with various phishing and security settings in Outlook

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and Office 2010 x64 Pro.  I have the latest updates on Windows, IE8, Firefox (normally my default), and Office.  I have all the UAC turned on because I want principle of least privilege :-).  Of course as I said, I've already tried on my admin account and still no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have any group policies defined on the machine that could be having an effect?

Comment: I'm going to try and look.  I didn't see anything in the "Local Security Policies" but I'll check my group policies right now.  I never added anything explicitly, but perhaps Microsoft Security Essentials (should have mentioned that I have that) or some other setting implicitly adds the restriction there.

Comment: Just checking back...I went through all the policies and couldn't find anything.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

#### Step to resolve this issue: ([*Source*](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7programs/thread/6df90823-228a-45a3-b50c-69d20a745b77))

1. [Click] **Start** buton
2. Type in: *Default Programs*
3. Hit [Enter] on *Default Programs*
4. [Click] **Set program access and computer defaults** (*It's 4th option in the list*)
5. [Click] the **down arrows** for *Custom*
6. Choose Internet Explorer and Outlook
7. [Click] **OK**
8. Restart the system

*Note: Changes only take effect after a full reboot*.